# Execute multiple java methods asynchronously and get the results on job done

Tags: java, multithreading

how to execute multiple java methods asynchronously and get the results on job done for each method?
Lets say I have this:

```
for(int i=1; i<=10000; i++) {
    kur(i);
}

//on kur(i) finish -> System.out.println(kur(i)) or System.out.println(Exception e)


Info kur(int i) throws Exception {
   //do some stuff
   return new Info(...);
}
```

I can use spring boot also. I checked this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/ but it is different than my case.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(ORIGINAL ANSWER) Maybe an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) could help you?

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10000)
         .forEach(i -> {
             executorService.submit(() -> {
                 try {
                     System.out.println(kur(i));
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     // do something useful here - remember you're in a separate thread
                     //
                     // this is not useful.
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             });
         });

executorService.shutdown();
executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

(EDIT WITH POOR MAN'S SOLUTION TO WAIT FOR EVERYTHING TO COMPLETE):

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    List<Future<?>> futures = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10000)
                                       .mapToObj(i -> {
                                           return executorService.submit(() -> {
                                               try {
                                                   System.out.println(kur(i));
                                               } catch (Exception e) {
                                                   // do something useful here - remember you're in a separate thread
                                                   //
                                                   // this is not useful.
                                                   e.printStackTrace();
                                               }
                                           });
                                       })
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (Future<?> f : futures) {
        f.get();
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: btw if I put something after IntStream it is executed before the stream ends. How I can put for example logger.info("Done") after all in the stream is finished ?

Comment: If you log something immediately after the awaitTermination call, you can be sure that everything has finished. Be cautious - the 1 minute timeout was arbitrary. If you have long running jobs, you might need to wait longer!

Comment: the problem is that I have lots of jobs with different time and I cannot calculate the time needed to do all the jobs. I have 2 threads and they will be used for lets say 1000 jobs the jobs are lets say 2 seconds each of them. The best way is to count the jobs in forEach statement and when the counter tick at 1000 to wait lets say 20 seconds more and then shutdown the executor. Or if I can do join with all these threads and when all is done my logger to be executed but I dont know how to do any of this ?

Comment: I've added an edit with a "poor man's solution" to allow you to wait for everything to complete!

Comment: It's a turn of phrase we use in England to mean "really simple, really dumb, probably not the most efficient or clever way of doing something - but, hey, it works!"